# Bootstrap datepicker in bootstrap modal, making page blank and adds year

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a bootstrap modal, and a form that is loaded via web2py ajax within that modal. My datepicker field is in that form and it doesnt activate since it is loaded via ajax. So I added a listener to catch the loaded ajax and activate the datepicker afterwards. Then when I click the field, it opens the datepicker, but then replaces the entire page content with the year? Here is a screenshot GIF of what happens:

[GIF link](http://imgur.com/nRovVFu)

EDIT:

As Sam requested, here is some code to help diagnose the issue:

```
/**
 * JS
 */

// Fill modal with content from link href
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {

  var link = $(e.relatedTarget);

  // this line loads the form via ajax
  $.web2py.component(link.attr("href"),'modal-body');

  // this listens for ajax and activates bootstrap datepicker after
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url == link.attr("href")) {
      $("#myModal").find('input.date').datepicker(
      );
    }
  });


});

/**
 * HTML
 */

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Deal</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also this error is called in the console, but not sure if this would affect the datepicker specifically, hopefully its helpful:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Comment: GIF link is broken

Comment: @SamHood its working perfectly I just clicked it

Comment: It's a 403, you'll have permission to view it but not us

Comment: @SamHood i changed the link, thank you!

Comment: Got it now! That's pretty weird behaviour, is there anything in the console / network tab when it does that? Also would be handy if you stuck some code snippets in your question to see if theres anything wrong there

Comment: @SamHood thanks Sam! I added the info above, including code snippets for HTML and JS as well as the console warning

Comment: That warning usually indicates that an AJAX call has tried to perform a synchronous request, not actually an error but just something to note.  I do notice though from your markup that you've not closed the div that has the class "modal fade" - was that missed out from copy/paste or is that an error?

Comment: @SamHood copy paste issue, my bad lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was failing was that datepicker would trigger a `show` event that was triggering the listener we used to load the modal content. Since its in a modal, it would use the wrong URL and load the dashboard page instead, which caused a failure because it was an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a z-index to datepicker

```
.datepicker{ 
      z-index:2000;
}
```

Comment: it opens, thats not the problem, the problem is that it blanks the page after opening. Look at the GIF above

Comment: Sorry, the GIF does not open, now I can see